# What does this function fract_exp_two do?

Tags: c

```
/* Does linear interpolation between powers of two */
static inline unsigned fract_exp_two(unsigned x, unsigned fract_bits)
{
        unsigned fract = x & ~(~0 << fract_bits);

        x >>= fract_bits;
        x   = 1 << x;
        x  += (x * fract) >> fract_bits;

        return x;
}
```

I came across a function, but I could not figure out what is does. What result it returns? I tried some arguments, but hardly found any clues.Is there any explanation?

Comment: `~` = bitwise NOT, `<<` left shift, `&` bitwise AND, `>>` right shift...

Comment: I exactly knew these and what each step computes, but can not find out what it returns, even with the English comments. (Sorry for my poor understanding of English).

Comment: It appears to be a slightly peculiar decoder for a custom binary floating-point format, much like IEEE-754 except without all of the complicating special-cases. To be specific it splits `x` into two bitfields, with `fract_bits` defining the width of the lower part. The upper part is interpreted as the power-of-two exponent, while the lower part is interpreted as a fixed-point fraction (the mantissa). It then multiplies the two together, with an implicit one. Google for half-float decoders and you'll probably find relevant explanations of the basic principles.

Answer (score 0):

After tips from @doynax  and referenced this link, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format.

I figured out how it worked.

A x is formed by 2 parts, one (high part `x >>= fract_bits` in this function) is exponent (pow of 2), and one (low part `fract = x & ~(~0 << fract_bits)` in this function) is fraction part (also pow of 2). Unless high part is all zeros, it implicitly represent 1 `(x = 1<<x)`. So final part `x  += (x * fract) >> fract_bits` means 1+mantissa * exponent part.
It's a method to encode float point with 2bytes data type.